# programming 2048 with matlab

Tags: matlab, 2048

I'm actually new to matlab and trying programming this game...The problem is when i input 2 or 6 my program must add a random new number between 2 and 4 instead of zero but it doesn't..pls help me to find where is the problem...I'm almost sure for loops are right and i kinda guess the problem is in the while loops...sorry for my language..thanks

```
for i=1:2
    a1=rand;
  if a1>0.666666
    b1=4;
  else
    b1=2;
  end
    c1=round(3*rand + 1);
    c2=round(3*rand + 1);
    A(4,4)=0;
    A(c1,c2)=b1;
end
disp(A)
while 2>1
      S=input('direction')
      if S==2
      for i=1:4
        if A(2,i)==0
          A(2,i)=A(1,i);
          A(1,i)=0;
        end
        if A(3,i)==0
          A(3,i)=A(2,i);
          A(2,i)=A(1,i);
          A(1,i)=0;
        end
        if A(4,i)==0
          A(4,i)=A(3,i);
          A(3,i)=A(2,i);
          A(2,i)=A(1,i);
          A(1,i)=0;
        end
        end
     for i=1:4
        if A(4,i)==A(3,i);
            A(4,i)=2*A(3,i);
            A(3,i)=A(2,i);
            A(2,i)=A(1,i);
            A(1,i)=0;
        end
        if A(3,i)==A(2,i);
            A(3,i)=2*A(2,i);
            A(2,i)=A(1,i);
            A(1,i)=0;
        end
        if A(2,i)==A(1,i)
            A(2,i)=2*A(2,i);
            A(1,i)=0;
        end
        end
     a2=rand;
     if a2>0.666666
       b2=4;
     else
       b2=2;
     end
  while 3>1
       x1=round(3*rand+1);
       x2=round(3*rand+1);
     if A(x1,x2)==0
       break
     end
     if find(A)==16
          break
     end
  end
  if find(A)~=16
    A(x1,x2)=b2;
  end
  end
  if S==8
  for i=1:4
    if A(3,i)==0
       A(3,i)=A(4,i);
       A(4,i)=0;
    end
    if A(2,i)==0
       A(2,i)=A(3,i);
       A(3,i)=A(4,i);
       A(4,i)=0;
    end
    if A(1,i)==0
         A(1,i)=A(2,i);
         A(2,i)=A(3,i);
         A(3,i)=A(4,i);
         A(4,i)=0;
    end
   end
   for i=1:4
    if A(1,i)==A(2,i)
       A(1,i)=2*A(2,i);
       A(2,i)=A(3,i);
       A(3,i)=A(4,i);
       A(4,i)=0;
    end
    if A(2,i)==A(3,i)
       A(2,i)=2*A(3,i);
       A(3,i)=A(4,i);
       A(4,i)=0;
    end
    if A(3,i)==A(4,i)
        A(3,i)=2*A(3,i);
        A(4,i)=0;
    end
    end
    a3=rand;
    if a3>0.666666
      b3=4;
    else
      b3=2;
    end
   while 1
      x3=round(3*rand+1);
      x4=round(3*rand+1);
    if A(x3,x4)==0
       break
    end
    if find(A)==16
        break
    end
   end
   if find(A)~=16
      A(x3,x4)=b3;
   end
  end
  if S==6
  for j=1:4
     if A(j,2)==0
        A(j,2)=A(j,1);
        A(j,1)=0;
     end
     if A(j,3)==0
        A(j,3)=A(j,2);
        A(j,2)=A(j,1);
        A(j,1)=0;
     end
     if A(j,4)==0
        A(j,4)=A(j,3);
        A(j,3)=A(j,2);
        A(j,2)=A(j,1);
        A(j,1)=0;
     end
  end
  for j=1:4
    if A(j,4)==A(j,3);
       A(j,4)=2*A(j,3);
       A(j,3)=A(j,2);
       A(j,2)=A(j,1);
       A(j,1)=0;
    end
    if A(j,3)==A(j,2)
       A(j,3)=2*A(j,2);
       A(j,2)=A(j,1);
       A(j,1)=0;
    end
    if A(j,2)==A(j,1)
       A(j,2)=2*A(j,1);
       A(j,1)=0;
    end
  end
  a4=rand;
  if a4>0.666666
    b4=4;
  else
    b4=2;
  end
 while 2>1
   x5=round(3*rand+1);
   x6=round(3*rand+1);
  if A(x5,x6)==0
    break
  end
    if find(A)==16
        break
    end
 end
 if find(A)~=16
   A(x5,x6)=b4;
 end
end
 if S==4
 for j=1:4
     if A(j,3)==0
        A(j,3)=A(j,4);
        A(j,4)=0;
     end
     if A(j,2)==0
        A(j,2)=A(j,3);
        A(j,3)=A(j,4);
        A(j,4)=0;
     end
     if A(j,1)==0
        A(j,1)=A(j,2);
        A(j,2)=A(j,3);
        A(j,3)=A(j,4);
        A(j,4)=0;
     end
  end
  for j=1:4
     if A(j,1)==A(j,2)
        A(j,1)=2*A(j,2);
        A(j,2)=A(j,3);
        A(j,3)=A(j,4);
        A(j,4)=0;
     end
     if A(j,2)==A(j,3)
        A(j,2)=2*A(j,3);
        A(j,3)=A(j,4);
        A(j,4)=0;
     end
     if A(j,3)==A(j,4)
        A(j,3)=2*A(j,4);
        A(j,4)=0;
     end
  end
  a5=rand;
  if a5>0.666666
     b5=4;
  else
     b5=2;
  end
 while 2>1
     x7=round(3*rand+1);
     x8=round(3*rand+1);
   if A(x7,x8)==0
        break
    end
    if find(A)==16
        break
    end
  end
  if find(A)~=16
    A(x7,x8)=b5;
  end
 end
 disp(A)
 end
```

Comment: There is too much repeated code in here, which makes it difficult to understand and easy to miss errors.  Try writing a few functions that wrap the repeated code, for example the section that collapses and slides the numbers, either row-wise or columnwise.  Or the section that chooses random coordinate.  After the main logic code is condensed, it will be easier to debug

Comment: The [Matlab debugger](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html) might be a useful tool to localise your problem.

Comment: Type "dbstop if error" in matlab console

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this code as a startingpoint. In the cases you write functions for w-s-a-d that accept V as input and give a new V back as output.

```
close all
fig=figure(1);clf
eventKey = @(src, event) set(gcf,'Tag',event.Key);
set(fig, 'WindowKeyPressFcn', @(src,event) eventKey(src,event))
V = zeros(4);
V(2,3)=2;
V(1,4)=4;
T=fig.Tag;
go=true;
while go
    if sum(V(:)==0)==0,disp('gameover');go=0;end
    clf
    plot([0,0,4,4,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,0,0,4,4,0],[0,4,4,0,0,0,4,4,0,0,4,4,3,3,2,2,1,1],'-k')
    axis image off
    axis([-.5 4.5 -.5 4.5])
    for i = 1:4
        for j = 1:4
            if V(i,j)~=0
                text(i-.5,j-.5,num2str(V(i,j)))
            end
        end
    end
    pause(0.01)
    drawnow
    if ~strcmp(T,fig.Tag)
        T=fig.Tag;
        switch T
            case 'w'
                V
            case 's'
                V
            case 'a'
                V
            case 'd'
                V
            case 'escape'
                go=0;
        end
        T='idle';
        fig.Tag='idle';
        V=V(:);
        s=rand([numel(V),1]);[~,idx]=sort(s);
        i=find(V(idx)==0,1,'first');
        V(idx(i))=2;
        V=reshape(V,[4,4]);
    end
end
```